# Find __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler caller

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I have an app which is periodically triggering a "Collection was mutated while being enumerated." exception.  The frequency of the exception seems to vary across devices.

I have a breakpoint set on all exceptions thrown, but at the time the exception is thrown, the only stack I get is __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler and the assembly code it calls.  I get the memory address for the __NSArrayM that's being modified, but I can't figure out how to reverse-engineer this into the name or contents of the array.  Typing `image lookup --address 0x20087d10` (the address the exception prints) in lldb gives me no output.  `$r0` gives me the exception object, but both `po [$r0 callStackSymbols]` and `po [$r0 callStackReturnAddresses]` return nil.

I also can't figure out how to determine which section of code is triggering it; the contents of the application threads at the time the exception breakpoint is hit vary from incident to incident and do not include any obvious accesses to collection objects.

How do I figure out which collection is being mutated and triggering this exception?

Comment: By the by and for the curious, the cause of the error was that I was registering and removing a NSURLProtocol subclass unnecessarily, and when I happened to do so while a web request was triggering a CoreFoundation search for a matching protocol, it caused this exception.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was overcomplicating things - one can reference memory addresses directly at the lldb command line, so `po 0x20087d10` is sufficient to print the description of the object at 0x20087d10.

(Murphy's law of StackOverflow... when you *finally* give up and post it on StackOverflow, you *finally* figure it out yourself.)